# How can I remove the part of the object that is inside the (hollow)cylinder?

Tags: edit-mode

[image: Photo to show you the objects]

How can I remove the part of the object on the right that is inside the cylinder?

I also want to remove the part that sticks out:

[image: question 2]

How can I do that?

EDIT:
New screenshots to show the objects:
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's hard to understand what your object looks like, could you please share the file or a part of it?   https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I edited the original post and added more screenshots. tell me if you can see the objects more clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you've made a good topology but anyway if I've correctly understood what you want and if I wanted to do it quickly I would use the *Knife* tool

[image]